# Selecting and moving anchor points based on User input

Tags: illustrator-scripting, javascript

I am pretty now to scripting inside Adobe Illustrator.

I made a basic script, that opens UI window, where user input three dimensions and the output is three variables X, Y, Z.

[image: UI window]

What I want:

I want to move anchor points, like the move (enter) tool do. So when the **X=200,** all the anchor points in **section A and D**  will move 200mm to the left[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Is it possible to select some "regions" of the document, to tell which anchor points to move?